# diff -r only for certain file types

Tags: command-line, find, diff

Is there a way I can perform a recursive diff of two directories but only compare (in their respective places) files that match a specific filename or filetype predicate?

E.g. I would like to do *something* like

```
diff -r dir-a dir-b -filenames *.java, ivy.xml, build.xml
```

... or even better:

```
diff -r dir-a dir-b -filetype text
```

Clearly it is not mandatory to use `diff` as I suppose an incantation with `find` and `-exec diff` might also do the trick (I just don't know how to generate the complementary filepaths in the latter case).

Comment: There's an option to exclude files that match a pattern, I don't see an option to include only files that match the pattern.

Comment: All the options specific to comparing directories can be found at http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Comparing-Directories.html#Comparing-Directories

Comment: see this [*link*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775377/how-do-you-diff-a-directory-for-only-files-of-a-specific-type) and see the Sérgio answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10131908/2707864

Answer (score 2):

## Shellscript `differ-r`

This shellscript can perform a recursive diff of two directories but only compare (in their respective places) files that match a specific filename or filetype pattern.

```
#!/bin/bash

greenvid="\0033[32m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
 echo "Usage: compare files in two directories including subdirectories"
 echo "         $0 <source-dir> <target-dir> <pattern>"
 echo "Example: $0  subdir-1     subdir-2     \"*.txt\""
 exit
fi

cmd='for pathname do
        greenvid="\0033[32m"
        resetvid="\0033[0m"
        echo -e "${greenvid}diff \"$pathname\" \"${pathname/'\"$1\"'/'\"$2\"'}\"${resetvid}"
        diff "$pathname" "${pathname/'\"$1\"'/'\"$2\"'}"
    done'
#echo "$cmd"

find "$1" -type f -name "$3" -exec bash -c "$cmd" bash {} +
```

### Demo

Files:

```
$ find -type f
./1/ett.txt
./1/two.doc
./1/t r e.txt
./1/sub/only-one.doc
./1/sub/hello.doc
./1/sub/hejsan.doc
./differ-r2
./differ-r1
./differ-r
./2/ett.txt
./2/two.doc
./2/t r e.txt
./2/sub/hello.doc
./2/sub/hejsan.doc
```

Usage:

```
$ ./differ-r
Usage: compare files in two directories including subdirectories
         ./differ-r <source-dir> <target-dir> <pattern>
Example: ./differ-r  subdir-1     subdir-2     "*.txt"
```

Running `differ-r`:

The performed `diff` command lines are printed with green text and the output, when there is no match is printed with default text (white on black in the following screenshot).

[image]

```
$ ./differ-r 1 2 "*.doc"
diff "1/two.doc" "2/two.doc"
diff "1/sub/only-one.doc" "2/sub/only-one.doc"
diff: 2/sub/only-one.doc: No such file or directory
diff "1/sub/hello.doc" "2/sub/hello.doc"
2d1
< world
diff "1/sub/hejsan.doc" "2/sub/hejsan.doc"

$ ./differ-r 1 2 "*.txt"
diff "1/ett.txt" "2/ett.txt"
2c2
< stabben
---
> farsan
diff "1/t r e.txt" "2/t r e.txt"
1c1
< t r e
---
> 3
$ 

$ ./differ-r 1 2 "*"
diff "1/ett.txt" "2/ett.txt"
2c2
< stabben
---
> farsan
diff "1/two.doc" "2/two.doc"
diff "1/t r e.txt" "2/t r e.txt"
1c1
< t r e
---
> 3
diff "1/sub/only-one.doc" "2/sub/only-one.doc"
diff: 2/sub/only-one.doc: No such file or directory
diff "1/sub/hello.doc" "2/sub/hello.doc"
2d1
< world
diff "1/sub/hejsan.doc" "2/sub/hejsan.doc"

$ ./differ-r 2 1 "*"
diff "2/ett.txt" "1/ett.txt"
2c2
< farsan
---
> stabben
diff "2/two.doc" "1/two.doc"
diff "2/t r e.txt" "1/t r e.txt"
1c1
< 3
---
> t r e
diff "2/sub/hello.doc" "1/sub/hello.doc"
1a2
> world
diff "2/sub/hejsan.doc" "1/sub/hejsan.doc"
```

## `rsync` with filter

If you need not get any output describing the difference, only know which files are different or missing (so that `rsync` would like to copy them), you can use the following command line.

```
rsync --filter="+ <pattern>" --filter="+ */" --filter="- *"--filter="- */"  -avcn <source directory>/ <target directory>
```

### Demo

```
$ rsync --filter="+ *.doc" --filter="+ */" --filter="- *"  -avcn 1/ 2
sending incremental file list
./
sub/
sub/hello.doc
sub/only-one.doc

sent 276 bytes  received 35 bytes  622.00 bytes/sec
total size is 40  speedup is 0.13 (DRY RUN)

sent 360 bytes  received 41 bytes  802.00 bytes/sec
total size is 61  speedup is 0.15 (DRY RUN)
olle@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/test/test0/temp $ rsync --filter="+ *.txt" --filter="+ */" --filter="- *" -avcn 1/ 2
sending incremental file list
./
ett.txt
t r e.txt
sub/

sent 184 bytes  received 29 bytes  426.00 bytes/sec
total size is 21  speedup is 0.10 (DRY RUN)
```

If you want a clean output without commenting lines and without directories, you can `grep` the output like so,

```
$ pattern="*.doc"; rsync --filter="+ $pattern" --filter="+ */" --filter="- *"  -avcn 1/ 2 | grep "${pattern/\*/.\*}"
sub/hello.doc
sub/only-one.doc
```

### Shellscript `rsync-diff`

This one-liner can be made into the core command of a shellscript `rsync-diff`.

```
#!/bin/bash

LANG=C

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
 echo "Usage: compare files in two directories including subdirectories"
 echo "         $0 <source-dir> <target-dir> <pattern>"
 echo "Example: $0  subdir-1     subdir-2     \"*.txt\""
 exit
fi

pattern="$3"; rsync --filter="+ $pattern" --filter="+ */" --filter="- *" \
 -avcn "$1"/ "$2" | grep "${pattern//\*/.\*}" | grep -v \
  -e '/$' \
  -e '^sending incremental file list$' \
  -e '^sent.*received.*sec$' \
  -e '^total size is.*speedup.*(DRY RUN)$'
```

Answer (score 1):

With shell supporting [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) you can use the following one-liner (as already noted by @JammingThebBits):

```bsh
diff -r dir-a dir-b --exclude-from=<( \
find dir-a dir-b -type f -not \( -name '*.xml'  -or -name '*.java' \) \
| sed 's:^.*/\([^/]*\)$:\1:' \
)
```

It works like this: `find` search for the files not-of-interest, `sed` extract the basename (running `basename` is extremely slow if you have many files) and the puts them in a *temporary* file; such file is then passed to `diff` telling it to exclude them from the comparison (double exclusion = inclusion).

If you do not have command substitution put the `sed` output in a file and explicitly pass it to `diff`.

In the example I searched only for XML and JAVA file, change them as needed by separating them with OR.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned "Clearly it is not mandatory to use diff",

This should  do the job for you **meld**  easily configurable for what kind of files types to ignore:

[image]

moreover another alternative would be to write a simple script which will 
transfer from a white list to a black list and afterwards the black list will be passed to the diff with the `--exclude` option.

Comment: updated tags to add 'command-line'